# Does MySQL support a number or digit wildcard pattern?

Tags: mysql, variables, select, numbers

I want to select titles that have a number after a certain character. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%- H(any number)'
```

How would I select any number in this statement 1-10000000 if the number exists?

Comment: There is a regular expression search, and I'm sure that someone who is better than me could figure out the regular expression for what you are looking for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title REGEXP '.*- H[0-9]+'
```

That seems like the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: So is `%` in `LIKE` queries. @user989990: Yes, that's what the + is for.

Comment: I tried it on a test query and it did work for numbers like 20. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title RLIKE '- H[:digit:]{1,7}$';
```

will give you 1-9999999

Answer (score 1):

Use [a regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT ...
  FROM table
 WHERE title REGEXP '- H([1-9][0-9]{0,6}|10000000)$'
;
```